# How to validate a form that uses Dropzone.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, dropzone.js

I want to validate my form before the files are sent. I have this HTML code:

```
<form role="form" action="#" id="my-dropzone" class="dropzone form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="gal_id" value="{$galeria.gal_id}">
    <div class="form-body">
        <div class="alert alert-danger display-hide">
            <button class="close" data-close="alert"></button>
            Você tem alguns erros no formulário. Por favor, verifique abaixo.
        </div>
        <div class="alert alert-success display-hide">
            <button class="close" data-close="alert"></button>
            O formulário foi validado com sucesso! Aguarde.
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3">Ativo</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <input type="checkbox" name="active" value="1" class="make-switch" data-on-color="success" data-off-color="danger" data-on-text="SIM" data-off-text="NÃO" {if $galeria.gal_active==1 or !$livre}checked{/if}>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3">Título <span class="required"> * </span></label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Título" class="form-control required" minlength="2" maxlength="100" value="{$galeria.gal_title}">
            </div>
        </div>
        <h3 class="form-section">Imagens</h3>
        <div class="dropzone-previews">
            <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload fa-3x pull-left hidden-xs hidden-sm"></i>
            <div class="pull-left">
                <h4 style="margin-top: -10px;">
                                        <strong>Arraste e solte ou clique aqui para enviar os arquivos</strong>
                                        <br><small>Formatos aceitos: JPG e PNG - Tamanho máximo: 5mb - Máximo de 500 arquivos</small>
                                    </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
                <button type="submit" class="btn green-meadow">{if !$livre}Adicionar{else}Salvar{/if}</button>
                <a href="{$endereco}/galerias/listar" class="btn default">Cancelar</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And here is my JS code:

```
var Galerias = function() {
    return {
        initForm: function() {

            var form = $('#my-dropzone');
            var error = $('.alert-danger', form);
            var success = $('.alert-success', form);

            form.validate({
                errorElement: 'span', //default input error message container
                errorClass: 'help-block help-block-error', // default input error message class
                focusInvalid: false, // do not focus the last invalid input
                ignore: "", // validate all fields including form hidden input

                errorPlacement: function(error, element) { // render error placement for each input type
                    if (element.parent(".input-group").size() > 0) {
                        error.insertAfter(element.parent(".input-group"));
                    } else if (element.attr("data-error-container")) {
                        error.appendTo(element.attr("data-error-container"));
                    } else if (element.parents('.radio-list').size() > 0) {
                        error.appendTo(element.parents('.radio-list').attr("data-error-container"));
                    } else if (element.parents('.radio-inline').size() > 0) {
                        error.appendTo(element.parents('.radio-inline').attr("data-error-container"));
                    } else if (element.parents('.checkbox-list').size() > 0) {
                        error.appendTo(element.parents('.checkbox-list').attr("data-error-container"));
                    } else if (element.parents('.checkbox-inline').size() > 0) {
                        error.appendTo(element.parents('.checkbox-inline').attr("data-error-container"));
                    } else {
                        error.insertAfter(element); // for other inputs, just perform default behavior
                    }
                },

                invalidHandler: function(event, validator) { //display error alert on form submit   
                    success.hide();
                    error.show();
                },

                highlight: function(element) { // hightlight error inputs
                    $(element)
                        .closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error'); // set error class to the control group
                },

                unhighlight: function(element) { // revert the change done by hightlight
                    $(element)
                        .closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); // set error class to the control group
                },

                success: function(label) {
                    label
                        .closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); // set success class to the control group
                },

                submitHandler: function(form) {
                    success.show();
                    error.hide();
                    $('button[type="submit"]', form).prop("disabled", true);
                    $('button[type="submit"]', form).html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Aguarde, enviando imagens...');
                }

            });

        },

        initDropzone: function() {
            Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
                url: endereco + '/src/galerias/upload.php',
                previewsContainer: ".dropzone-previews",
                clickable: ".dropzone-previews",
                acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
                autoProcessQueue: false,
                uploadMultiple: false,
                parallelUploads: 500,
                maxFiles: 500,
                maxFilesize: 5, // mb
                paramName: "file",
                init: function() {
                    var myDropzone = this;
                    $.get(endereco + '/src/galerias/getpics.php', function(data) {
                        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                            var file = {
                                serverId: value.name,
                                size: value.size
                            };
                            myDropzone.options.addedfile.call(myDropzone, file);
                            myDropzone.options.thumbnail.call(myDropzone, file, galerias + "/galerias/" + value.name);
                        });
                    });
                    this.element.querySelector("button[type=submit]").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                        initForm();
                        e.preventDefault();
                        e.stopPropagation();
                        myDropzone.processQueue();
                    });

                    this.on("sending", function() {
                        $('button[type="submit"]').prop("disabled", true);
                        $('button[type="submit"]').html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Aguarde, enviando imagens...');
                    });
                    this.on("error", function(files, response) {
                        alert('Ocorreu um erro no envio dos arquivos.');
                    });
                    this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function(file) {
                        alert("O limite máximo de arquivos foi excedido.");
                    });
                    this.on("complete", function(file) {
                        if (this.getUploadingFiles().length === 0 && this.getQueuedFiles().length === 0) {
                            window.location.href = endereco + '/galerias/listar';
                        }
                    });
                    this.on("addedfile", function(file) {
                        var removeButton = Dropzone.createElement("<button class='btn red btn-xs btn-block'>Excluir</button>");

                        var _this = this;

                        removeButton.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            e.stopPropagation();

                            _this.removeFile(file);
                        });

                        file.previewElement.appendChild(removeButton);
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    };
}();
```

When I click the submit button, the form is validated by the **initForm();** function included in this lines:

```
this.element.querySelector("button[type=submit]").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    initForm();
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    myDropzone.processQueue();
});
```

That is the problem! The form is validated: ok! But now I need after the form is validated, it returns to the function that makes the files to be uploaded.

And it is also necessary that after validating the form, it is submitted if there are files to be sent or not.

How can I do that?
Thanks guys!

Comment: Why are you calling your `initForm()` on the `click` of the `submit` button?  `"init"` is the "initialization" of the plugins, therefore, you simply do this once on DOM ready, then the jQuery Validate plugin will automatically capture the `submit` button.  In other words, if you do it correctly, you would not need a `click` handler for the `submit` button.

Comment: I don't know if I understand you, but let's say I put a `Galerias.initForm();` in my code and remove this `initForm();` in the Dropzone.js function. I tried here and the form is validated when I start to type, for example, but when I click the submit button with a empty form, the form is submitted anyway, and file upload starts. I think I need to do that in the button click because the Dropzone plugin. Correct me if I'm wrong @Sparky Thanks!

Comment: Before you can successfully integrate this with another plugin, you have to get the validation plugin working properly.  [See the tag wiki page for basic usage](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info).  The `.validate()` method gets called once on DOM ready and the submit button click is handled automatically... you **never** need a `submit` or `click` event handler or listener to facilitate its normal operation.

Comment: So I need to put the Dropzone function inside the `submitHandler` function? I need the two plugins working when the page is loaded.

Comment: `submitHandler` is a function that is only fired when the form is valid and the button is clicked.   I am not familiar with dropzone, or I would have posted the answer below.   My guess is that `dropzone` also needs to be initialized within DOM ready.  Then you need to read the documentation for both plugins to see which callback functions & options to use within each other.

Comment: Yes, I think it's `submitHandler` because I only need to upload the files when the button is clicked. I am searching and trying a way to do that, thanks for the help @Sparky!